# Where is "Show position of the mouse when the Control key is pressed"

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

I am using Ubuntu 13.04.

CTRL Key in VirtualBox is not working for me, that's because the "Show position of the mouse..." is hogging the CTRL key.

I don't see an option to disable this in the Mouse settings. Any idea what is going on? Any way to modify this behavior without the GUI?

[image: Setting not available]

Comment: It is very weird how little control the System Settings->Mouse actually gives you. It's scandalous!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might or might not, work.

Install Dconf editor:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Open Dconf and navigate to:

```
org -> gnome -> settings deamon -> peripherals -> mouse
```

There should be a setting there titled `locate-pointer`.

[image]

If it's not there, then I don't think its possible to change this.  Very weird it defaults to on...

Comment: At least with Nautilus 3.14.3 be were of [this bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=125618) that don't let you copy (Ctrl+C) filenames.

Answer (score 1):

This feature has been removed in newer versions of Gnome (3.6 and up) so you will no longer be able to change this. If you upgraded from a previous version of Ubuntu that is probably why you have this issue.

I would suggest doing a fresh install.