# Left ctrl key not working in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, xorg, keyboard

I have just upgraded to Ubuntu 13.04 and the left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key has stopped working. How would I go about diagnosing the problem?

I had to downgrade my X server to enabled legacy graphics card support, but everything else seems to be fine.

---

**Edit:**

`xev` output for left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>:

```
KeymapNotify event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967235 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
           0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

`xev` output for right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0xc3, subw 0x0, time 10191367, (-206,519), root:(827,656),
    state 0x14, keycode 105 (keysym 0xffe4, Control_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Comment: Execute command: xev

Comment: I think @konrad wants to see the event generated when you press the left ctrl key. In my machine, it shows something like this when I pressed Left Ctrl key

`KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0x291, subw 0x0, time 98520655, (301,491), root:(1582,519),
    state 0x10, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False`

Comment: `KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0x291, subw 0x0, time 98520903, (301,491), root:(1582,519),
    state 0x14, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False`

Comment: Interesting - does this mean I have a key mapped that is suppressing the normal `ctrl` key behaviour?

Comment: @ThomasBratt did you find a solution? I have a very similar problem in ubuntu 19.10...

Comment: Sorry - I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I would press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> and the computer would restart (with a message that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> was pressed). Then I noticed that the problem is with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key - in the terminal, when I pressed just the left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key it would output sometimes e.g. "5~;5~" other times it would keep printing "-----------" or "vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv". The output in the terminal without X was different and also a bit erratic.

This started happening after I upgraded to 13.04. I also had the "locate mouse pointer" feature enabled from one of the earlier versions of Ubuntu and Gnome - it would render red/brown circles around the mouse pointer when you press the left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key. After disabling this feature [1], the problem seems to have gone away.

[1] [Where is "Show position of the mouse when the Control key is pressed"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264361/where-is-show-position-of-the-mouse-when-the-control-key-is-pressed)